# Aggregate dataframe into a frequency table

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am looking to reshape a dataframe from something which looks like this, with variables:

```
Year, University, Degree, Gender
```

With each row depicting an entry of a student, eg:

```
2017, University College London, Social Science, Male 

2017, University of Leeds, Social science, Non-Binary
```

I would like to create a frequency table from this data in order to condense the number of rows so that for each university, there are 19 rows for each of the degree categories, and then for each Degree, the count/frequency for each gender is shown, which would look something like this.

```
Year University Degree [Gender (Male, Female, Non-Binary)]

2017 UCL Biological Sciences 1 0 2
```

I hope this makes sense. Thank you for the help.

EDIT: 
I would now like to be able to plot this data as a line graph using a subset of the data. I am currently subsetting outside of the plotting function like so

```
   subsetucl <- TFtab[which(TFtab$University == 'University College London'),]
ggplot(data=subsetucl, aes(x=Year, y=Female, group=Degree, color = Degree)) + geom_line()+ geom_point(size = 0.8) + xlab("Year of application") + ylab("Frequnecy of Females") + ggtitle("UCL Applications by Degree (2011-2017)") + theme_bw()
```

What is the best way to subset the data within the plotting function and how do I best display lines for all Genders rather than just female frequencies. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a very solution with dplyr.

```
library("dplyr")
data %>%
   group_by(University, Degree, Gender) %>%
   count( )%>% 
   spread(key = Gender, value = n, fill = 0)
```

But seriously use the search function on stack overflow. [Here's a book to help with R](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/)

Comment: This is helpful, but the frequencies for the gender are all in one column rather than separate columns for each gender level. This also removes 0 values. Is there a way to keep 0 values as well?

Comment: `data %>% 
  group_by(Univesity, Degree, Gender) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  spread(key = Gender, value = n, fill = 0)`

Comment: This adds 0s for the rows with values in but for whole rows with 0 there is no row. Is there a way to do this too? @svenhalvorson

Answer (score 0):

**1) aggregate/model.matrix** Try this one-line aggregate solution. No packages are used.

```
aggregate(model.matrix(~ Gender + 0) ~ Year + University + Degree, DF, sum)
```

giving:

```
  Year                University         Degree GenderFemale GenderMale GenderNon-Binary
1 2017       University of Leeds Social science            1          0                1
2 2017 University College London Social Science            0          1                0
```

**2) aggregate/cbind** It would also be possible to write out the `model.matrix(...)` part using `cbind(...)` like this which may be clearer although tedious:

```
aggregate(cbind(Female = Gender == "Female", Male = Gender == "Male",
            `Non-Binary` = Gender == "Non-Binary") ~ Year + University + Degree, DF, sum)
```

giving the following which is the same as above except for a slight variation in the column names:

```
  Year                University         Degree Female Male Non-Binary
1 2017       University of Leeds Social science      1    0          1
2 2017 University College London Social Science      0    1          0
```

**Note:** The input used in the example above in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "Year, University, Degree, Gender 
2017, University College London, Social Science, Male 
2017, University of Leeds, Social science, Non-Binary
2017, University of Leeds, Social science, Female"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: Assuming "doesn't seem to work" means that you just want to aggregate the values rather than have a full n-way table I have revised the answer to use aggregate.